# adding a string into hash table

Tags: python, python-3.x, hashtable

Trying to add an insert(self, key) method that inserts the key into the appropriate position while linear probing for resolving collisions.
My current code, I'm just not 100% sure how to inset the str into the hash table.

Testing code:

```
#Test
my_table  = HashTable(5)
my_table.insert('hello')
print("Hashtable:", my_table)
```

result:

```
Hashtable: [None, None, None, None, 'hello']
```

---

```
class HashTable:

    def __init__(self, capacity): 
        self.capacity = capacity 
        self.slots = [None] * self.capacity

    def __str__(self): 
        return str(self.slots )

    def is_empty(self): 
        return self.slots.count(None) == len(self.slots)

    def hash(self, key):
        sum = 0
        for char in key: 
            sum += ord(char) 
            sum2 = "%04d" % (sum) 
            digits = int((sum2[2]) + (sum2[3])) 
            number = int(digits * digits) 
        return number % len(self.slots)


    def insert(self, key): 
        count = 0 
        position = key%self.capacity 
        if self.slots[key%self.capacity] == None: 
            self.slots[key%self.capacity] = key 
        else: 
            while self.slots[position] != None: 
                position +=1 
                if position >= self.capacity: 
                    position = 0 
            self.slots[position%self.capacity] = key 
            return self.slots
```

Im currently getting a Type error

```
>>>TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting line 25, in insert
    position = key%self.capacity
```

I just need some advice on how to add the string into the hash table.

Comment: Which line gives the error? Please post the full error.

Comment: I added it into the error statement, its the line which says position = key % self.capactiy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`key` (`'hello'`) is a string object. You need to convert it to integer to do modulo. Otherwise it will perform [`printf`-style string formatting](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#old-string-formatting); causes error because there's no `%` in the string:

```
position = key % self.capacity
```

Call `self.hash` to get hash value:

```
def insert(self, key): 
    position = self.hash(key) % self.capacity 
    if self.slots[position] == None: 
        self.slots[position] = key 
    else: 
        while self.slots[position] != None:
            position += 1
            if position >= self.capacity: 
                position = 0
        self.slots[position%self.capacity] = key
        return self.slots
```

**UPDATE** `if` body can be merged into `else`:

```
def insert(self, key): 
    position = self.hash(key) % self.capacity
    while self.slots[position] != None:
        position += 1
        if position >= self.capacity:
            position = 0
    self.slots[position%self.capacity] = key
    return self.slots
```

Comment: When i tried to print it out I got this as the output for some reason..                  >>> Hashtable: [None, 840651671246116861, None, None, None]

Comment: instead of >>> Hashtable: [None, None, None, None, 'hello']

Comment: @M.Jones, Thank you for your feedback. I updated the code to address the issue you mentioned.

Comment: any ideas why it prints on second position instead of last >>>Hashtable: [None, 'hello', None, None, None]

Comment: @M.Jones, I missed that there's `hash` method in the class. I updated the code to use `self.hash` instead of builtin `hash` function.

Comment: would you have any idea on how to return the number of keys? I tried to do def size(self): return len(self.slots) but that returns the size of the table instead of the number of keys

Comment: like have this my_table  = MyHashTable(11)
my_table.insert('hello')
print(my_table.size())
and the result should be 1 , because only one key is inserted

Comment: @M.Jones, I would add another instance attribute to keep track of the number of keys. `self.key_count = 0` (increase in `insert` method).

Comment: @M.Jones, Or you can use `len(self.slots) - self.slots.count(None)` (total minus the number of `None`s)

Comment: oh yeah i see the self.slot - self.slot.count makes sense thanks again!